# where to ask questions for discussion

Tags: discussion

one of the main guidelines is to ask questions that can be answered, and not questions open for discussion.

where do I ask questions that are borderline? (meaning I am not sure it has a definitive answer, and fairly certain it will start a discussion)

Comment: In the channel chat room I would guess, especially if it bring discussion. (If it look more ontopic we will just direct to the site in worst case)